# How to Use IF and ELSE in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

```
Create user //Is my test case name
        ${random_string}=    Generate Random String    8    [LOWER]
        Set Global Variable  ${random_string}
        ${body}=  create dictionary  email=${random_string}@mail.com  firstName=${random_string}  lastName=${random_string}  role=ADMIN
        ${response}=  Post On Session  mysession  /user  json=${body}  headers=${headers}   //This is One Response for POST Method
        ${getuserresponse}=  GET On Session  mysession  /user  headers=${headers}  //This is 2nd response for GET method which return all the users
     FOR  ${i}  IN  @{getuserresponse.json()}   
        #Validation
            IF  ${i['firstName']}  ==  ${random_string}  // I want to check weather GET Response contains email that I send from POST request
                Log  User Created Successfully
            ELSE
                Log  User Not Created Successfully
        END
```

Instead it gives me Error as
Evaluating IF condition failed: Evaluating expression 'ptrmipuy'(this is random_string) failed: NameError: name 'ptrmipuy' is not defined nor importable as module

Comment: You may need to add quotes around string in IF like this: `"${i['firstName']}"  ==  "${random_string}"`

Comment: @Pekka
When I added quotes
it show error below
Evaluating IF condition failed: Evaluating expression '"name" ==' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions cannot have sequences with two or more spaces, since that's what robot uses to parse a statement. Everywhere you have  `==`  it needs to be `==`

Also, your expressions either need to quote the string values or you can use the special syntax that converts the robot variables into python variables.

```
IF  "${i['firstName']}" == "${random_string}"
```

-or-

```
IF  $i['firstName'] == $random_string
```

This is covered in the documentation for the BuiltIn library, in a section titled [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet of if else, if it works then copy paste this syntax and replace your variable. Also print your variable before comparing, if it has extra quotes, then you might get that error.

Also you should have only space before and after this symbol "=="

```
*** Test Cases *** 
Testifelse
    ${Variation}=    Set Variable    NA
    IF    "${Variation}" == "NA"
        Log  if  
    ELSE 
        Log  else
    END
```